# Facebook Developer - List of Facebook Pages for a Particular Categories

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am fairly new to this.

Is it possible to get the list of facebook pages for one or more categories. (ie. Musicians / Travels) etc.

I may not have liked all the pages. But I am looking for all the musicians pages from a particular country.

I am after total no of likes and total posts today etc...

Is this possible?

If yes, can you point me to the right direction. Is it possible to get this info in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `/search` API to search anything on facebook, but am afraid you can not search for what you are desiring.

```
GET graph.facebook.com
    /search?
    q={your-query}&
    [type={object-type}](#searchtypes)
```

Check out the *Searching* article in this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search).

You'll find that if your `search type` is **Page**, the `q` could be the **{name}**. So, I dont think you can search pages with the categories.

[Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dmusic%26type%3Dpage)

The above example will search all the pages on facebook having "music" in their name. But searching with having *category: music*, is not possible I guess.